# Dynamically Including/Excluding Jobs in Gitlab Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Pipeline that has a few stages: `detect, test, build, deploy`

The `detect` stage detects the type of application and the `test` and `build` stages have jobs that are included or excluded based on what is computed in `detect`.  The `detect` stage writes it's value to a environment variable called `BUILD_MODE`.

I am using `rules` like so:

```
ng-build:
  extends:
    - '.ng/job/build'
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $BUILD_MODE == "ANGULAR"
      when: always

npm-build:
  extends:
    - '.npm/job/build'
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $BUILD_MODE == "NPM"
      when: always
```

The problem with this is that the `BUILD_MODE` variable is evaluated statically when the pipeline is created not after the `detect` stage runs so the above never works unless I set the variable explicitly in the top level YML file like so:

```
variables:
 BUILD_MODE: "ANGULAR"
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?  The summary of what I want to do is evaluate some condition, either set the stages dynamically or set the variable itself before the stages in the Pipleline are created so they will be created with the rules evaluated correctly.

Comment: i am curious what would be the goal of this approach/what is the project look like. Do you attempt to build one generic build file for all your projects?

Comment: @SimonSchrottner one example (mine) is roughly like this: I have a mobile app that can be build in 3 different colors/environments (call them red, blue, green). But my client pays per build - some clients may want red and blue, some may want only green... I build red, green & blue each in a separate job, which checks some config and exits early if this client didn't pay for this colour. But all 3 jobs have to run because we have no way to dynamically determine this ahead of time/modify the pipeline while it is running. It seems "dynamic pipelines" are the current solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [dynamic child-pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines). Maybe you could solve your problem by dynamically creating your npm/ng build jobs.